# Change storage engine for mysql system tables?

Tags: mysql, innodb, amazon-rds, myisam

I am in the process of changing the storage engine for my tables in MySql. There are some tables in the mysql schema which use the MyISAM storage engine:

> mysql.columns_priv
>   mysql.db
>   mysql.event
>   mysql.func
>   mysql.ndb_binlog_index
>   mysql.proc
>   mysql.procs_priv
>   mysql.proxies_priv
>   mysql.tables_priv
>   mysql.user

Now, I need to change the storage engines because AWS RDS does not support encryption for MyISAM, apart from other reasons.

Should I change the storage engines for the mentioned tables? Will it impact the way MySQL works?

**Edit:**
I mixed up two different things. 
RDS does support encrypting databases using MyISAM engine. But you can't encrypt existing instances. What I am trying to do is encrypt an existing RDS instance by taking a snapshot of it --> encrypting the snapshot --> restoring the encrypted snapshot. RDS does not support taking snapshots of tables using MyISAM engine.
I made a misleading summary that RDS doesn't support encrypting MyISAM.

Comment: Some of those tables aren't even real tables, they are purely virtual to offer you means to fetch data about the structure of the database using SQL queries. They are like `/proc` on Linux.

Comment: @Havenard Thanks, I didn't know that. So they are something like in-memory structures and not stored on disk?

Comment: To some extend yes. The information in those tables shouldn't be considered sensitive anyway, it's technical stuff. Name of fields, tables, database users and their permissions, passwords too but those are encrypted.

Comment: @Havenard you are thinking of `information_schema`, which does not consist of real tables.  The tables in the `mysql` schema are indeed real tables with .frm and .myd/.myi files backing them.

Comment: @AdeelSiddiqui where do you see that *"RDS does not support encryption for MyISAM*"...?  If the RDS instance has encryption enabled, the entire system is on an encrypted EBS volume (hidden, managed by the RDS service.)  RDS does not support point-in-time recovery of MyISAM because MyISAM tables aren't transactional... but RDS quietly locks the tables in the `mysql` schema whenever it makes a backup so that they are clean on the snapshot. (Undocumented but observable.)

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for pointing that out. I botched that up. What I am trying to do is encrypt an existing RDS instance by taking a snapshot of it --> encrypting the snapshot --> restoring the encrypted snapshot. RDS does not support taking snapshots of tables using the MyISAM engine. I made a misleading summary that RDS doesn't support encrypting MyISAM.

Comment: It is not quite true that RDS does not support snapshots of MyISAM tables.  It takes additional precautions for the tables in the `mysql` schema to ensure that they are properly quiesced -- even though this is not documented -- they get flushed and locked for snapshots, and will snapshot without difficulty.  Your planned action is fine, with the system tables as they are.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot But that's what the AWS console says when I try to take a DB snapshot. "This feature is currently supported for InnoDB storage engine only. If you are using MyISAM, refer to details."

Comment: No!  Upgrade to version 8.0 to get more of what you want -- including the elimination of all the MyISAM system tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I change the storage engines for the mentioned tables?

No.

> Will it impact the way MySQL works?

Yes. It is likely to make the server stop working -- either immediately, or on restart.

Don't mess with the MySQL system tables.

Comment: Sound advice.  [**Important**
*"Do not convert MySQL system tables in the mysql database from MyISAM to the InnoDB type. This is an unsupported operation."*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html)